# Unknown column in 'field list' for a primary key value?

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving an error that I'm struggling to overcome - I've inserted numerous echo statements in order to figure out what is actually happening, however I still haven't managed to resolve the issue. Here is the PHP code:

```
class Payment extends DAO {
    private $table = "fss_Payment";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->table);
    }

    public function addPayment($totalAmount){
        $queryAddPayment = sprintf("
        INSERT
        INTO
          fss_Payment(amount, paydate, shopid, ptid)
        VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
            , $totalAmount
            , date("Y-m-d")
            , 1
            , 2
        );

      echo $queryAddPayment;
      parent::query($queryAddPayment);
    }

    public function getPayment(){
      $queryGetPayment = "
        SELECT
          payid
        FROM
          fss_Payment
        ORDER BY
          payid DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ";

        $e = new \Exception;
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());

      return parent::query($queryGetPayment);
    }

    public function addAndGetPayment($totalAmount){
      $this->addPayment($totalAmount);
      return $this->getPayment()->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
?>
```

The getPayment() method is where the error is, the query is returning the following error:

```
Unknown column 'payid' in 'field list, despite the table has a payid field.
```

I understand that the fields are inserted correctly, but the problem lies in retrieving those queries. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Post your table schema

Comment: The mysql connectors offer built-in method to retrieve the auto increment value of the last inserted record, no need to write your own.

Comment: `sprintf` is not a replacement for prepared statements.